# Approaches to port Flash swf files to android?

Tags: android, actionscript, air, flash

Firstly I am new to flash . I have got a swf running project which uses 10-12 swf files. And my client wants me to port the same to android. Flash projects consist of animations and small videos(I actually have no idea about how this is coded).

Now I tried

Approach 1--> using it in webView , It works but not that fine as in windows .

Approach 2--> using Adobe air 2.6(A very lengthy method ) It worked but in awkward way (It is flickering and popping)

Now what could be the possible approach to handle this problem Please help I am totally new to this?

Answer (score 1):

The best approach for you is to create a Mobile Air Application.

It depends on which IDE you are using 
In Flash Develop, you choose Project->New Project->AIR Mobile AS3 App. 
In Flash Professional you choose File->new-> Air For Android.

Furthermore it depends on type of application and functionality you are creating. To simply display swf's you would create Loader and load them dynamically. It will work on Android just fine.

```
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
var url:URLRequest = new URLRequest("my.swf");
loader.load(url);
addChild(loader);
```

see http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Loader.html

However if you plan in future to port your project to IOS, and swfs contains code, this approach will not work.

Answer (score 0):

CyberProdigy is right for the most part.
I would like to add, that with the newer versions of AIR you can pack multiple SWF's even for iOS app.

More details about loading and packing are here are here:
http://blogs.adobe.com/airodynamics/2012/11/09/packaging-and-loading-multiple-swfs-in-air-apps-on-ios/